# react native runtime error while using react native cli

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, runtime-error

the error is "unable to load script. Make sure you are either running metro(run 'react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release"

I researched a lot but the only answer I could find was making an assets folder than making changes to the blacklist.js file and running a script. but my project does not contain any blacklist.js file.

[image]

Comment: blacklist.js in your node_modules you can see the path one the error getting that time in your red screen below show the actual path of it

Comment: one more possible think you forgot to start your `npm run` that run your metro server